# Why is there a memory leak C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, char

I am implementing a class to store the list of students belonging to a class. As I am using `char` arrays to store information, I have to frequently resize the 2D arrays.

However, in my test software when I call the following two lines (See section 1), the memory significantly increases.

```
Section 1

for(int i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
{
    StudentClass studentClass;
    studentClass.resizeArray(1000);
}
```

This is my header file...

```
#define NAME_SIZE 35
#define SUBJECT_SIZE 25

class StudentClass
{
private:
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    char subject[SUBJECT_SIZE];
    int numberOfStudents;
    char **studentChar;

public:
    StudentClass();
    ~StudentClass();

    void setStudentName(char *name);
    void setStudentAge(int age);
    void setStudentSubject(char *subject);
    void resizeArray(int n);
}
```

This is the function giving memory leak...

```
void StudentClass::resizeArray(int n)
{
    int i;
    int newStudentName=1;
    char **temp;
    if(n < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Number of students within a class can't be less than 0" << endl;
    }
    else if(n == numberOfStudents)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(n == 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
        {
            delete[] studentChar[i];
        }

        delete[] studentChar;
        studentChar = NULL;
        numberOfStudents = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = new char*[n];
        if(n < numberOfStudents)
        {
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = studentChar[i];
            }

            for (; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
            {
                delete[] studentChar[i];
            }

            delete[] studentChar;
            studentChar = temp;
            numberOfStudents = n;
        }
        else
        {
            for (i=0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = studentChar[i];
            }

            for (; i<n; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = new char[128];
                sprintf(temp[i], "NewStudent_%02d", newStudentName++);
            }

            delete[] studentChar;
            studentChar = temp;
            numberOfStudents = n;
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know why there is a memory leak. I really suck at these kind of things.

Comment: It looks good to me. Have you used a tool like `valgrind` to determine that there's really a leak? I think you may just be seeing the result of memory fragmentation.

Comment: I think it's more likely that the leak is in your code rather than in the language itself.

Comment: Rule #1: Ensure there is a matching `delete` for every `new` for every code path. Rule #0: Encapsulate your `new` and `delete` into RAII facilities, preferably through libraries or alternatively by yourself, such that #1 is automatically fulfilled. Rule #-1: Do not do unnecessary dynamic allocations, such that #1 and #0 are not necessary.

Comment: Please post a main() program to see how you're using your class.  I can easily create a leak in your code with a 3 line main() program.

Comment: What does your StudentClass destructor method do?  (if it's not doing the right thing, that would cause a memory leak on each iteration of your for loop)

Comment: You should post a complete but minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using prebuilt tools, like `std::vector` and `std::string`? Even if you want to implement the behavior yourself, you should use an object for each resource and make sure that they clean up after themselves

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code with [Deleaker](http://deleaker.com) and got the following ([a link to full sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEuhB.png)):

[image: Leaks]

After releasing the memory in destructor, no more memory leaks (Task Manager proves it):

```
~StudentClass()
{
    resizeArray(0);
}
```